# Set theme in tinymce editor in codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, tinymce

How can we config tinymce editor in codeigniter like in wordperss. theme with all option

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this pretty neat tutorial: http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/integrating-wysiwyg-tinymce-codeigniter